# Getting readLines to read a website as a single line of text

Tags: r

I'm trying to get readLines() to read a website, and for the html from that website to be read into R as a single line of text. Is this possible?

Comment: By single line do you mean no carriage returns etc. (CHR(13) and CHR(10). What have you tried so far? When you have a specific error or issue with existing code we can help.

Comment: Sorry for not being descriptive enough. My intent is to use gregexpr on the line to get all instances of the pattern I'm looking for (a product name) and then run a regexec that uses that product name as a starting point to find the price. I'm only familiar with regular expressions operating on a line-by-line basis, and the prices are not a consistent distance from the product name, so making the html code into a single line was the route I took, I was just wondering if there was a way for R to automate it instead of me saving the website and then joining the lines in Notepad++.

Comment: knowing that carriage returns was what my google search needed to entail got me an answer very fast, thanks so much ElectricLlama!
` paste(data, sep='\t', collapse='')` did the trick!

Comment: Excellent! You should document that as an answer and accept it so many more people can solve this with a google search on 'single line of text' :)

Comment: @tendollarbanana We encourage you to answer your own question if you've found a solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! This was my first time :)

Answer (score 0):

```
paste(data, sep='\t', collapse='')
```

This line of code will remove all the carriage returns from an input.